# Firestore realtime listeners for Angular: How to make listeners start sequentially?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two Firestore listeners. The second listener can't start until data from the first listener is available. How do I make the second listener wait to start until the first listener hears data?

I have the listeners in Angular's `ngOnInit` to start on page load. The first listener gets `videoTitle` from Firestore. The second listener uses `videoTitle` to dynamically set the location in Firestore it listens to.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    const unsubUsers = onSnapshot(doc(this.firestore, 'Users', this.user.uid), async (doc) => {
      if (doc.exists()) {
        this.user = doc.data() as User;
        this.videoTitle = doc.data()['lastVideoWatched'];
      } else {
        console.error('No such document!');
      }
      // unsubUsers();
    });

    const unsubClipInMovieWatching = onSnapshot(doc(this.firestore, "Users/" + this.user.uid + "/" + this.homeToolbarObject.language2.long + "/Videos/" + this.videoTitle?.snake_title, "Clip_In_Movie_Watching"), async (doc) => {
      if (doc.exists()) {
        this.clipInMovieWatching = doc.data()['clip'];
      } else {
        console.error("No such document!");
      }
      // unsubClipInMovieWatching();
    });
}
```

This throws the error `No such document!`. The listener doesn't start, no data is passed to the components, and the app doesn't load the view. If I hardcode `videoTitle` everything works.

In a child component I can wait for `videoTitle` to appear:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['videoTitle']) { // waits until the Firestore listener gets the videoTitle
        console.log("VideoTitle available: " + this.videoTitle);
        // do something 
    }
  };
```

This doesn't work in the parent component. This throws an `undefined` error on page load and never logs on subsequent changes.

Nesting the second listener in the first listener didn't work.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    const unsubUsers = onSnapshot(doc(this.firestore, 'Users', this.user.uid), async (doc) => {
      if (doc.exists()) {
        this.user = doc.data() as User;
        this.videoTitle = doc.data()['lastVideoWatched'];
        const unsubClipInMovieWatching = onSnapshot(doc(this.firestore, "Users/" + this.user.uid + "/" + this.homeToolbarObject.language2.long + "/Videos/" + this.videoTitle?.snake_title, "Clip_In_Movie_Watching"), async (doc) => {
            if (doc.exists()) {
              this.clipInMovieWatching = doc.data()['clip'];
            } else {
              console.error("No such document!");
            }
            // unsubClipInMovieWatching();
          });
        // unsubUsers();
      } else {
        console.error('No such document!');
      }
    });
}
```

This throw an error:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>' has no call signatures.
```

Does that means that `unsubClipInMovieWatching()` can never be called? If I want to keep the listener open until the user logs out, can I skip setting up `unsubClipInMovieWatching()`?

Using `async...await` didn't help. Are listeners not async because they don't return a Promise?

Putting the optional `?` into `this.videoTitle?.snake_title` helped a little. This prevented this error when `this.videoTitle` was undefined:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'snake_title')
```

But the listener never started.

Answer (score 0):

I got the second listener to start without waiting for the first listener but this is making me suspect that my thinking about the problem is flawed.

I hadn't set a default instantiation for `videoTitle`. I'd made this:

```js
videoTitle: string;
```

When I made a default:

```js
videoTitle: string = 'Walker_Climbs_a_Tree';
```

the listener starts.

However, when I click buttons in the app to change the video or the clip that I'm watching, the second listener never logs the changes. I'm thinking that, yes, you can dynamically set the database location that a listener listens to, but then changing that variable won't make the listener change the database location it listens to.

I'm thinking that the use case for a listener has two conditions:

1. Use a listener for data that changes. The user can select to watch a different video, so the video title changes. The number of clips in a video doesn't change, so don't use a listener to get the number of clips in a video.
2. Don't use a listener when the database location of the data changes. When the user selects a new video, the number of clips in the video changes, but it's the location of the data that's changing, not the data in a location that's changing.

The mistake I made was to not see that `clipInMovieWatching` is changing in two ways. The user can change the clip without changing the video. This is a use case for a listener. But the user can also change the video, which moves the location in the database of the data I want to listen to. This isn't a use case for a listener.